# I have Nishita Sky Texture in my scene, but is not working properly

Tags: shaders

I have a problem with Nishita. It seems to work fine on my viewport, but when I try it on sneak peek (Verge3D) the scene is completely back.

[image: Text]

I notice that if I use a HDRi's it works fine, it seems to be a problem with Nishita in particular. I also notice that the preview in the world tap is black no matter what i change or do, despite that is working on my viewport.

[image: Text]

If I enable SunDisk it wont shown in the sky either, no matter the size of the Sun or intensity.

Any help will be much appreciate!! Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: I would suppose this node is just not compatible with the addon, currently